# Add group after details row

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to add a group after the details row as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O49t.png)

However, it does not seem to be possible to add a group after the details row. You can only add a group (Parent or Child) before the details row. Just wanted to check if this is indeed the case where grouping cannot be added after the details row?

Comment: do you mean a column group, not a row group? If you mean the product type column shown in your image then you cannot add this directly. I'm sure there is a way round it though, I'm sure I've done this myself or answered a question on SO about it. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: If you do mean a row gorup then just right-click on the details rowgroup in the groups pane (under the main design windows) and add a total group (or parent gorup) "after"